# sails.js one-to-one association created as one-way association

Tags: model, associations, sails.js, waterline

I noticed I was not getting the same response on a post as I was on a get. Specifically, associations.

Referencing 'Create new record while associating w/ another new record'
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/blueprint-api/Create.md

I recreate the scenario from the documentation with `sails new testProj`, then `sails generate api pony` and `sails generate api pet`, then update the models to have a one-to-one association.

Pony

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        pet: {
            model: 'pet'
        }
    }
};
```

Pony

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        pet: {
            model: 'pet'
        }
    }
};
```

Pet

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        pony: {
            model: 'pony'
        }
    }
};
```

Then, `sails lift` away.

`POST /pony`

JSON Req

```
{
  "name": "Pinkie Pie",
  "hobby": "ice skating",
  "pet": {
    "name": "Gummy",
    "species": "crocodile"
  }
}
```

JSON Res

```
{
  "name": "Pinkie Pie",
  "hobby": "ice skating",
  "pet": 1,
  "createdAt": "2014-11-21T19:18:09.161Z",
  "updatedAt": "2014-11-21T19:18:09.161Z",
  "id": 1
}
```

As you can see, the `res`ponse did not include the full pet object, just its id. In the documentation, it shows the full object being returned.

The entries and the association were definitely created successfully,

`GET - /pony/1`

```
{
  "pet": {
    "name": "Gummy",
    "species": "crocodile",
    "createdAt": "2014-11-21T19:18:09.157Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-11-21T19:18:09.157Z",
    "id": 1
  },
  "name": "Pinkie Pie",
  "hobby": "ice skating",
  "createdAt": "2014-11-21T19:18:09.161Z",
  "updatedAt": "2014-11-21T19:18:09.161Z",
  "id": 1
}
```

Is this an error in documentation, or an error in code? Either way, is there a way we can specify that we want the associations to be returned?

One-to-one associations are just showing up as the linked id, many to many do not show up at all. I was looking into the `toObject()` function for `waterline` for another issue when I saw the `showJoins` option; it looks like it might be related to that.

In addition, this one-to-one association is actually only being created as a one-way association.

After completing the same as above:

`GET - /pet/1`

```
{
  "name": "Gummy",
  "species": "crocodile",
  "createdAt": "2014-12-03T20:50:31.346Z",
  "updatedAt": "2014-12-03T20:50:31.346Z",
  "id": 1
}
```

Notice that no pony is returned.

Just to make sure...

`GET - /pony/1/pet`

```
{
  "name": "Gummy",
  "species": "crocodile",
  "createdAt": "2014-12-03T20:50:31.346Z",
  "updatedAt": "2014-12-03T20:50:31.346Z",
  "id": 1
}
```

`GET - /pet/1/pony`

`Res`

`Specified record (1) is missing relation 'pony'`

Pony has a pet, pet has no pony.

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `via`attribute while defining two-way relations, otherwise they're assumed to be unrelated one-way joins.

Pony

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        pet: {
            model: 'pet',
            via: 'pony'
        }
    }
};
```

Pet

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        pony: {
            model: 'pony',
            via: 'pet'
        }
    }
};
```

It's mentioned in the docs for only in [`many-many`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html) and `one-many` relations, which might be an error.

Comment: You don't need the 'via' for a one-to-one association https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/associations/one-to-one.md

Comment: one-to-one associations only work from the model that holds the foreign key. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27752329/129808 for more information.