# I am confused with Sails.js waterline one-to-one association logic

Tags: node.js, orm, associations, sails.js, waterline

So the reason why im confused, because I am a PHP developer and used Laravel and FuelPHP alot

What i dont really understand is the association it self.

What i mean, i wanted to create a basic hasOne / BelongsTo logic, with the following

User has one profile

Profile belongs to an user

I am used to the following build up (Laravel style)

**Users table**

```
id | username    | email     | password 
---------------------------------------
1  | My Username | My email  | 1234568
```

**Users_profile table**

```
user_id | first_name    | last_name      
----------------------------------------
1       | My First name | My Last name
```

Then i just defined models this way

**User model**

```
class Users extends Eloquent 
{
    public function profile() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne('profile');
    }
}
```

**Profile model**

```
class Profile extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $tableName = 'users_profile';

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And it just works, because the `return $this->hasOne('profile');` will auto check for the `user_id`

Tried the same in Sails.js (in the sails way)

**User model**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    username: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true,
        email: true,
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    profile: {
      model: "profile",
    }

  },
};
```

**Profile model**

```
module.exports = {

    tableName: 'user_profile',

    autoPK: false,

    autoCreatedAt: false,

    autoUpdateddAt: false,

  attributes: {

    user_id: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true
    },

    first_name: {
        type: 'string',

    },

    last_name: {
        type: 'string',

    },

    user: {
      model: "user"
    }

  }
};
```

And reading from the documentation now i have to update my table this way

```
id | username    | email     | password | profile
-------------------------------------------------
1  | My Username | My email  | 1234568  | 1



user_id | first_name    | last_name    | user |
-----------------------------------------------
1       | My First name | My Last name |  1
```

So i need to store 2 more id's again, and i do not really get why.

Than i read further tried to use `via` did not work (noted that is for collections)

So, anybody could give me a logic example for a Laravelis style?

Foud nothing about this in the docs (a more easier way), because in my opinion if the user will have more relations, this will cause and ID hell (just my aopinion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2398#issuecomment-64453204) that Sails doesn't fully support one-to-one associations; you have to set the foreign key on whichever side you want to be able to populate from.  That is, if you want to have `User` #1 linked to `Profile` #1 and be able to do `User.find(1).populate('profile')`, you would set the `profile` attribute of `User` #1, but that doesn't automatically mean that doing `Profile.find(1).populate('user')` will work.  This is as opposed to *many-to-many* relationships in Sails, where adding the link on one side is sufficient.  That's because *to-many* relationships use a join table, whereas *to-one* relationships do not.

The reason this hasn't been a priority in Sails is that one-to-one relationships are usually not really useful.  Unless you have a [really compelling reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321323/345484) for not doing so, you're better off just merging the two models into one.

In any case, if it's something you really need, you can use the [`.afterCreate` lifecycle callback](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) to ensure a bi-directional link, for example in `User.js`:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {...},

  afterCreate: function(values, cb) {

    // If a profile ID was specified, or a profile was created 
    // along with the user...
    if (values.profile) {
      // Update the profile in question with the user's ID
      return Profile.update({id: values.profile}, {user: values.id}).exec(cb);
    }

    // Otherwise just return
    return cb();
  }
};
```

You could add a similar `.afterCreate()` to `Profile.js` to handle updating the affected user when a profile was created.

Comment: Did not know about this issue.
And thanks for the heads up and for the detailed answer

Comment: Did not realize this was an issue either. You'd figure this would be worth mentioning in the docs...

Comment: There's now an [entire page in the docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-one) dedicated to it.